# Why ChartJS's Bar Chart does not render bar for a specific value?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am using ChartJS v 2.8.0

I am using following data, but it does not show bar for "4.01":

`data:[9.24, 6.28, 5.65, 6.74, 4.01, 17.15, 4.01]`

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels:["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
          label: '# of Votes',
          data:[9.24, 6.28, 5.65, 6.74, 4.01, 17.15, 4.01],
        borderWidth: 1
        }
        ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
                    reverse: false
        }, 
      }],
        xAxes: [{
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```css
canvas { background-color : #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="200"></canvas>
</body>
```

When I use slightly different data it works perfect:

`data:[9.24, 6.28, 5.65, 6.74, 4.01, 17.15, 3]`

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels:["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
          label: '# of Votes',
          data:[9.24, 6.28, 5.65, 6.74, 4.01, 17.15, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
        }
        ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
                    reverse: false
        }, 
      }],
        xAxes: [{
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```css
canvas { background-color : #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
</body>
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it some kind of bug? How to fix it?

Comment: You are required to post your code here, within your question, and NEVER a third party site: [mcve]

Comment: @Rob Sorry review now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `beginAtZero: true` in `yAxes.ticks` for both charts which will allow you to specify that the scale starts at 0.

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [9.24, 6.28, 5.65, 6.74, 4.01, 17.15, 3],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false,
          beginAtZero: true
        },
      }],
      xAxes: [{}]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="200"></canvas>
</body>
```

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [9.24, 6.28, 5.65, 6.74, 4.01, 17.15, 4.01],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false,
          beginAtZero: true
        },
      }],
      xAxes: [{}]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="200"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks but why? 
While it works for some values without setting beginAtZero: true

Comment: In the case where there are two data points with value  4.01, 4.01 becomes the smallest number in your data. Depending on how Chart.js determines the linear y-axis scale, it might start at 4.01. This means no bar is drawn as the value is equal to the lowest point of the y-axis

Comment: this makes sense but when I put 3 in last bar instead of 4.01, it works perfect while 3 should not have bar being smallest value if you are right.

Comment: It might also be considering some kind of threshold for the number